# Transparent JPanels in JLayeredPanes

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, transparent, jlayeredpane

I would like to have a JPanel transparent or fully invisible (not like panel.setVisible(false) but more something like opacity = 0.0f) which will then be put into a JLayeredPane, to make the bottom layer visible.

You know ask why. I need this to use the build in Layouts like BorderLayout and so on because I dont want to make my own layout and so on.

What I then tried was first of all the Implementation of a transparent JPanel which was more or less easy by doing just this:

```
public class ClearPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 706731555521208974L;

    private float opacity = 0.0f;
    private Shape shape = null;

    public ClearPanel() {
        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    public ClearPanel(float opacity) {
        setOpaque(false);
        setOpacity(opacity);
    }

    public ClearPanel(float opacity, Shape shape) {
        setOpaque(false);
        setOpacity(opacity);
        setShape(shape);
    }

// Here usually are some random getters and setters

     @Override
     public void paintComponent(Graphics go) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) go;
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        if(shape == null) shape = g.getClipBounds();
        g.setColor(new Color(getBackground().getRed(), getBackground().getGreen(), getBackground().getBlue(), 255*opacity));
        g.fill(shape);
    }

}
```

So what this does is usually creating a more or less transparent Version of the JPanel. And it also works if don't use a layout but fixed Positions and Sizes but when you program something bigger it would be way easier to use available solutions.

The problem comes now:
When I try to use this in a JLayeredPane with the possibility to see the bottom layer, nothing happens, although it definetly should I need this because I want a bottom panel with a background Image and then I want some stuff ABOVE that panel. And I thought, ok I know Layers from Gimp, maybe Java offers this, so thats why I think that JLayeredPane could help.

Do you know a possibility to make the bottomlayers shine trough an other  layer although you use a  fixed layout or do you think, I will need to make my own layout or use `public void paint(Graphics g)` of JFrame to paint them step by step ?

Thanks in advance

PS: Sry for my English but after one day of try and error I can't write anything "perfect" any more...

Comment: Have a look at `GlassPane`. There's one available by default in the [root pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)

Comment: Swing only deals with fully transparent and fully opaque components, using `setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));` will cause you a number of issues. Instead, you need to use `paintComponent` and "fake it" by filling the component with a transparent color of your choice